# mustache i18n with parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, mustache

I'm trying to use Mustache together with i18n (php, within Wordpress). I've got the basic __ functionality working nicely, something like this

```
class my_i18n {
  public function __trans($string) {
    return __($string, 'theme-name');
  }   
}
class mytache {
  public function __()
  {   
    return array('my_i18n', '__trans');
  }   
}
```

Then to output a template with an i18n string, I can simply do this

```
$context = new mytache;
$template = "<div>{{#__}}String to translate{{/__}}</div>";
$m = new Mustache;
echo $m->render($template, $context);
```

So far everything is fine. However, I want to be able to translate strings with parameters. i.e. the equivalent of `sprint_f(__('Account Balance: %s'), $balance);`.

It seems that if I do something like `{{#__}}Account Balance: {{balance}}{{/__}}` it doesn't work. I'm guessing because the inner tag gets converted first and therefore the translation cannot be found for the phrase.

Any ideas how to achieve this cleanly with Mustache?

UPDATE: here's the end-result snippet (with massive help from bobthecow):

```
class I18nMapper {
    public static function translate($str) {
        $matches = array();
        // searching for all {{tags}} in the string
        if (preg_match_all('/{{\s*.*?\s*}}/',$str, &$matches)) {
            // first we remove ALL tags and replace with %s and retrieve the translated version
            $result = __(preg_replace('/{{\s*.*?\s*}}/','%s', $str), 'theme-name'); 
            // then replace %s back to {{tag}} with the matches
            return vsprintf($result, $matches[0]);
        }   
        else
            return __($str, 'theme-name');
    }   
}   

class mytache {
  public function __()
  {   
    return array('I18nMapper', 'trans');
  }   
}
```

Comment: What keyword did you use to extract the strings from the mustache template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I added an i18n example here](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/commit/f77cf3729de0e46d6187da2353a4ab438657b6fe)... it's pretty cheesy, but the test passes. It looks like that's almost the same as what you're doing. Is it possible that you're using an outdated version of Mustache? The spec used to specify different variable interpolation rules, which would make this use case not work as expected.

Comment: This looks like the thing I was looking for... together with [this comment](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/issues/69#issuecomment-3347583) on github

Answer (score 0):

On my behalf I would suggest using normal, fully functional template engine. I understand, that small is great and everything, but for example Twig is much more advanced. So I would recommend it.

About mustache. Can't you just extend you translation method! For example you pass `{{#__}}Account Balance: #balance#{{/__}}`

```
function __( $string, $replacement )
{
    $replaceWith = '';

    if ( 'balance' == $replacement )
    {
        $replaceWith = 234.56;
    }

    return str_replace( '#' . $replacement . '#', $replaceWith, $string );
}

class my_i18n
{
    public function __trans( $string )
    {
        $matches     = array();
        $replacement = '';

        preg_match( '~(\#[a-zA-Z0-9]+\#)~', $string, $matches );

        if ( ! empty( $matches ) )
        {
            $replacement = trim( $matches[0], '#' );
        }

        return __( $string, $replacement );
    }
}

$Mustache = new Mustache();
$template = '{{#__}}Some lime #tag#{{/__}}';
$MyTache  = new mytache();

echo $Mustache->render( $template, $MyTache );
```

This is a very ugly example, but you can make it fancy yourself. As I see Mustache on it's own will not be able to do what you want.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This is not really solving the problem, and I wouldn't really call it clean. It makes things worse in some ways having to maintain all those tags and conditionals etc. It's surprising that Mustache doesn't appear to have built-in support for internationalization within templates.

Comment: Do one youself. Never said, that this is a clean solution. I the first parargaph already I suggested usage of a normal fully functional template engine. ;)